# SQL Server 2005 query works in SQL Server Management Studio Express but not in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2005, datetime, delphi-2010

I'm using SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Express and Delphi 2010. `Fecha_hora` = Date_Time is `smalldatetime`.

My date format is `dd/mm/yyy`

The dates in my table are saved like this:

```
08/01/2013 11:22:00 a.m.
```

I have this query in Delphi to know at which hours the sales are higher given a period of time; days/months, in this case I'm testing with the same day 8 Jan 2013:

```
  conect.Q_total_hora.Active:=false;
  conect.Q_total_hora.SQL.Clear;
  conect.Q_total_hora.SQL.Add('select datepart(hh, fecha_hora) as Hora, sum(Total) as Venta, a.tipo as Tipo');
  conect.Q_total_hora.SQL.Add('from ventas v join articulos a on v.id_articulo=a.id_articulo');
  conect.Q_total_hora.SQL.Add('where tipo='+char(39)+DBLUCB_tipo.Text+char(39)+' and cast(Convert(varchar(10), fecha_hora, 112) as datetime) between'+char(39)+DateToStr(DateTimePicker_fecha1.Date)+char(39)+ 'and'+char(39)+DateToStr(DateTimePicker_fecha2.Date)+char(39));
  conect.Q_total_hora.SQL.Add('group by datepart(hh,fecha_hora), a.tipo order by datepart(hh,fecha_hora) ');
  conect.Q_total_hora.Active:=true;
```

I use `cast(Convert(varchar(10), fecha_hora, 112) as datetime)` because I found on the internet that this way I can retrieve only the date without the time to retrieve data between dates.

In the `DateTimePickers` I choose `08/01/2013` as 8 Jan 2013

I used a memo to see the query `memo1.Text:=conect.Q_total_hora.Text;`

and the query I receive is:

```
select datepart(hh, fecha_hora) as Hora, sum(Total) as Venta, a.tipo as Tipo
from ventas v join articulos a on v.id_articulo=a.id_articulo
where tipo='Burrito Grande' and cast(Convert(varchar(10), fecha_hora, 112) as datetime) between'08/01/2013'and'08/01/2013'
group by datepart(hh,fecha_hora), a.tipo order by datepart(hh,fecha_hora)
```

The problem I have is that when I run this query in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, it returns values, but not in Delphi, and in Delphi if i set the  values of the `DateTimePickers` to `01/08/2013` as 1 Aug 2013 it returns the values of `08/01/2012`.

As far as I know (and I don't know much...) when I send a query to SQL Server it is like if I'm writing it in SQL... why if I'm sending the date `08/01/2013` as a string it doesn't return anything?

Thank you in advance. I'm not good in database, most things I look for them on the internet ^^

Comment: `BETWEEN` is terrible for this, as is converting to a string to get rid of time. Try `WHERE fecha_hora >= '20130801' AND fecha_hora < '20130802'`... see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx, http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime and http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time

Comment: What happens if someone enters `Jose's Burrito` for DBLUCB_tipo? (or creates a tipo with an apostrophe). This will lead to SQL syntax error. Parameterized queries will also avoid this problem! See also http://bobby-tables.com/delphi.html

Comment: @AaronBertrand I changed the way i deal with dates to yours, and it worked great, it might have not solved my question of why the code runs in SQL and not in delphi but it solved my problem and showed me a better way to use dates. Could you change it to an answere so i can set it as the answere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid `BETWEEN` for date range queries, as well as avoid any ambiguous date formats such as m/d/y or d/m/y. The query you end up with should look like this (how you get there in your delphi code I'll leave up to you):

```
WHERE fecha_hora >= '20130801' AND fecha_hora < '20130802'
```

But better yet, as the others have suggested, you should be passing the date value in via a parameter, e.g.

```
WHERE fecha_hora >= @date_param AND fecha_hora < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @date_param)
```

(If you need other cases other than single day, then use two parameters.)

For more background on date/range queries and why this is the way you should do it:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

And why you shouldn't use CONVERT to remove time from datetime:

- [What is the most efficient way to trim time from datetime?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime)
- [Trimming time from datetime – a follow-up](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time)

Answer (score 9):

You can avoid all these issues and wrote a very much cleaner code using  parameterized queries.

Try this

```
  conect.Q_total_hora.Active:=false;
  conect.Q_total_hora.SQL.Clear;
  conect.Q_total_hora.SQL.Add('select datepart(hh, fecha_hora) as Hora, sum(Total) as Venta, a.tipo as Tipo');
  conect.Q_total_hora.SQL.Add('from ventas v join articulos a on v.id_articulo=a.id_articulo');
  conect.Q_total_hora.SQL.Add('where tipo=:tipo and fecha_hora between :fecha1 and :fecha2');
  conect.Q_total_hora.SQL.Add('group by datepart(hh,fecha_hora), a.tipo order by datepart(hh,fecha_hora) ');
  conect.Q_total_hora.Prepared:=True;
  conect.Q_total_hora.ParamByName('tipo').AsString   := DBLUCB_tipo.Text;
  conect.Q_total_hora.ParamByName('fecha1').AsDateTime := DateTimePicker_fecha1.Date;
  conect.Q_total_hora.ParamByName('fecha2').AsDateTime := DateTimePicker_fecha2.Date;
  conect.Q_total_hora.Open;
```

Comment: Maybe that new query will work, but the question asks for an explanation of why the given query doesn't work, not for alternatives.

Comment: @RobKennedy, Why worry trying to find an explanation to an issue caused by a bad practice, as is passing datetime values as strings?

Comment: Because an explanation is what the question requests.

Comment: Giving a workaround and a advice, which is use parameters instead of use a literal sql sentence, is a valid answer too.

Comment: Using unparameterised queries without good reason is bad practice in general, using with DATE/DATETIME is even more so, for this very reason.

Comment: And avoids the possibility of SQL injection!

Comment: Side node: There was an issue in the past where .AsDateTime did not work with SQL server and we had to use .AsSQLTimeStamp (and then use DateTimeToSQLTimeStamp from the SqlTimSt unit). I forgot the exact details but mention it here just in case.

Comment: @RRUZ I tried this code and for some reason it didn´t work, but i really thank you for showing me another great and better way to write my code, from now on i will do it this way looking a little more into it :D Thanks!

Comment: While I admire the parameterized query, the `BETWEEN` is still extremely problematic, as I've explained elsewhere on this page.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
conect.Q_total_hora.SQL.Add('where tipo='+char(39)+DBLUCB_tipo.Text+char(39)+' and  fecha_hora between '+char(39)+DateToStr(DateTimePicker_fecha1.Date)+char(39)+ ' and '+char(39)+DateToStr(DateTimePicker_fecha2.Date)+char(39));
```

which should look like:

```
where tipo='Burrito Grande' and fecha_hora between '08/01/2013' and '08/01/2013'
```

SQL should convert the dates to datetime automagically and do the where you want.

You could also try this:

```
where tipo='Burrito Grande' and month(fecha_hora) = 8 and year(fecha_hora) = 2013 and day(fecha_hora) = 1
```

Comment: it does't work and i believe is because of the time in smalldatetime. it would work if i use `where tipo='Burrito Grande' and fecha_hora between '2013-08-01 00:00:00' and '2013-08-01 23:59:00'` but i want to use only dates

Comment: I strongly recommend against regional formats. Even I can't tell if you meant August 1st or January 8th.

Comment: Could you please describe what's different about your first suggested line of code? It looks similar to the original, and I was always lousy at those spot-the-differences games.

Comment: @RobKennedy - I replaced `cast(Convert(varchar(10), fecha_hora, 112) as datetime)` with `fecha_hora`

Answer (score 2):

If you use the term `BETWEEN '08/01/2013' and '08/01/2013'` you will indeed only see records having a date value of exactly '08/01/2013'.

If the column is of type `date` you will get what you want, but as your column type is `datetime`, the contents '08/01/2013 11:22' is not between '08/01/2013 00:00:00' and '08/01/2013 00:00:00' and hence ignored.

When querying a datetime column, use a pattern like this

```
...
where DateTimeCol between '<StartDate>' and '<EndDate> 23:59:59,997'
```

This might look a bit weird, but will include all datestamps from the given date range.

Update: This is a dirty solution which only works well with data type `DATETIME` but will not work with `SMALLDATETIME` or `DATETIME2`.

From my point of view there are two clean solutions: Either use

```
where (DateTimeCol>='<StartDate>') 
  and (DateTimeCol <'<The day following the EndDate>')
```

or separate date and time to two columns. Of course, only if possible and no ranges smaller than a day are required (eg one hour or so).

Comment: Note that this holds for parameterized queries as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. In fact, I tried to answer the original question only. The advantages of parametrized queries are explained in full already.

Comment: @alzaimar you can also use `StartOfTheDay`/`EndOfTheDay` functions from `DateUtils` when passing `Date/DateTime` values.

Comment: @LightBulb What would `EndOfTheDay` yield exactly? Does it understand the different data types, and how this can round up or miss data depending on whether the underlying data type is SMALLDATETIME, DATETIME, DATETIME2, etc.? Please see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx for why you never want to calculate the "end" of a range so that you can use BETWEEN - always calculate the start of the next range and use less than.

Comment: No, you definitely don't want `23:59:59,997` - what happens if the DateTimeCol changes to SMALLDATETIME? Your end range rounds up and you suddenly include data from the next day at midnight. What if it is DATETIME2? Now you might be missing a small number of rows that are > .997.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I know, it is a dirty solution, I should have mentioned that. You are right, the only good solution is to avoid BETWEEN and use two clause `(datecol>= start-of-day) and (datecol<next-day)`